# Java conditions for inputs

Tags: java, input, dialog, conditional-statements, equals

I have two classes. I am trying to make:

-The phone number of the customer not blank and is 10 characters
Otherwise re-enter

-The number of vehicles is between 1 and 10 (includes 1 and 10)
Otherwise re-enter

-The number of fuel tanks can only be (2, 4, 8, 10, 15, 20)
 
Otherwise re-enter

I don't know how to make phone number = 10 digits. After inputting values other than (1-10) on vehicles more than once, it jumps to number of fuel tanks. Same after inputting values other than (2, 4, 8, 10, 15, 20). What am I doing wrong? Help is appreciated. Thanks.

VehicleApp.Java segment of code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String firstname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your first name");
while (firstname.equals("")){
firstname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your first name");
}

String lastname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your last name");
while (lastname.equals("")){
lastname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your last name");
}

String phone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your phone");
while (phone.equals("")){
phone = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your phone");
}

int nbrVehicles = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of vehicles"));
if (nbrVehicles < 1 || nbrVehicles > 10){
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of vehicles");
}   

int nbrTanks = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of tanks"));
if (nbrTanks != 2 || nbrTanks != 4 || nbrTanks != 8 || nbrTanks != 10 || nbrTanks != 15 || nbrTanks != 200){
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of tanks");
} 

VehicleFactory vehicleObject = new VehicleFactory();
vehicleObject.HayloFactory(firstname, lastname, phone, nbrVehicles, nbrTanks);
vehicleObject.calcFuelTankCost();
vehicleObject.calcManufacturingCost();
vehicleObject.calcSubtotal();
vehicleObject.calcTax();
vehicleObject.calcTotal();
vehicleObject.getSummary();             
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `while`:

```
int nbrVehicles = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of vehicles"));
while (nbrVehicles < 1 || nbrVehicles > 10)
    nbrVehicles = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of vehicles"));
}
```